# Using np.where to find indices of array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

If I have an array :

```
array = 'KDI', 'KDI', 'KDU', 'KDA', 'ANU', 'AMU', 'BDU', 'CDU',
       'CDU', 'DAI', 'DAH', 'DBD', 'DDT', 'DDT', 'DDB', 'DDB',
       'UDM', 'UDM', 'DMA', 'DMH', 'DSX'], dtype='<U4')
```

and I apply :

```
for name in array:
    if name in array :
        idx_lookup = np.where(name==array)[0][0]
        print(idx_lookup)`
```

I got the result

```
0
0
2
3
4
5
6
7
7
9
10
11
12
12
14
14
16
16
18
19
20
```

meanhwile, what I want is, `[0,1,2,3,4,...,20]`. I want to find where is the match indices between two arrays using this for and if loop. in this case, I use exact same array, but I also want it applicable if the array are different and I want to find where is the same indices.
where is the mistake in the code ?

thanks

Comment: You take the first found index. As your `array` has the same element on the first two positions, the first found index for this element is `0` (for both cases), hence two zeros at the start. It's ambiguous in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some duplicates in your array.
You could count the duplicates in a dictionary.
Then return the index of the position of that exact value even if its a duplicate.

```
array=np.array(['KDI', 'KDI', 'KDU', 'KDA', 'ANU', 'AMU', 'BDU', 'CDU',
       'CDU', 'DAI', 'DAH', 'DBD', 'DDT', 'DDT', 'DDB', 'DDB',
       'UDM', 'UDM', 'DMA', 'DMH', 'DSX'], dtype='<U4')

found={}
for name in array:
    if name in array :

        if found.get(name) == None:
            found[name]=0
        else:
            found[name]+=1
        idx_lookup = np.where(name==array)[0][found[name]]
        print(idx_lookup)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### To get the output you want, you need the input elements to be unique

Currently you have two copies of "KDI", so your program is (correctly) identifying the second "KDI" as matching the first "KDI".

Here is a simple way to get the list you wanted with minimal modification to your code:

```
array = ['ZDI', 'KDI', 'KDU', 'KDA', 'ANU', 'AMU', 'BDU', 'CDU',
       'CDU', 'DAI', 'DAH', 'DBD', 'ZDT', 'DDT', 'ZDB', 'DDB',
       'ZDM', 'UDM', 'DMA', 'DMH', 'DSX']

for name in array:
    if name in array :
        idx_lookup = np.where(name==array)[0][0]
        print(idx_lookup)
```

#### Eventually you will need two different arrays, and a more efficient search

It is better to use the builtin tool to find an item in the list, than to search for it manually in the manner you have used.

```
array1 = ['ANU', 'CDU','MMM']
array2 = ['ZDI', 'KDI', 'KDU', 'KDA', 'ANU', 'AMU', 'BDU', 'CDU',
           'CDU', 'DAI', 'DAH', 'DBD', 'ZDT', 'DDT', 'ZDB', 'DDB',
           'ZDM', 'UDM', 'DMA', 'DMH', 'DSX']
for name in array1:
        if name in array2 :
            idx_lookup = array2.index(name)
            print(idx_lookup)
```