# Using NumPy to find indices of array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

If I have an array :

array = 'KDI', 'KDI', 'KDU', 'KDA', 'ANU', 'AMU', 'BDU', 'CDU',
'CDU', 'DAI', 'DAH'], dtype='<U4')
and I apply :

for name in array:
if name in array :
idx_lookup = np.where(name==array)[0][0]
print(idx_lookup)`
I got the result

0
0
2
3
4
5
6
7
7
9
10

meanhwile, what I want is, [0,1,2,3,4,...,10]. I want to find where is the match indices between two arrays using this for and if loop. in this case, I use exact same array, but I also want it applicable if the array are different and I want to find where is the same indices. where is the mistake in the code ?

thanks

Comment: why does this question look almost exactly like a question from 20 minutes ago by a different user : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75427787/using-np-where-to-find-indices-of-array/75427885#75427885

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75427787/using-np-where-to-find-indices-of-array/

Answer (score 0):

You've asked this question a few minutes ago, and received two answers.

Now you ask the same question, with the same typographical errors (your definition of `array` will not run, and your example output is not a list whereas you are asking for a list.

Review the answers in your earlier post.

Comment: Its a different user. this is indeed sketchy